# git surgery - splitting a repository and modifying the directory structure

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have the following single repository with this structure:

```
my-repo/
  foo/
    contents-of-foo
  bar/
    contents-of-bar
  baz/
    contents-of-baz
  other-contents
```

I wish to get the following structure, ideally without losing any history / tags:

```
new-combined-repo/
  contents-of-foo
  bar/
    contents-of-bar
  baz/
    contents-of-baz
```

and

```
my-other-repo
  other-contents
```

I'm a little stuck on how to proceed. I've tried this:

```
$ pushd path/to/my-repo/
$ git mv bar foo/
$ git mv baz foo/
$ git commit -m "Move bar and baz prior to repository extraction"
$ cd ..
$ git clone --no-hardlinks my-repo new-combined-repo
$ pushd new-combined-repo
$ git remote rm origin
$ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter foo \
      --prune-empty -- --all
$ git log --follow foo/bar/some-file
```

That has dropped all history for `some-file` prior to the `git mv` command.

Better suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a tree filter (for `git filter-branch --tree-filter`) that removes all directories but the ones you want to keep?  Like this one (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob dotglob
rm -r !(bar|baz|.gitignore)
```

This of course won't preserve histories of files that were moved *into* bar or baz, but apart from that uncommon case, the history will be kept intact.

Answer (score 1):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv bar baz foo; rm *'
```

Do save a copy of your repository before you mess around that `rm *`, please.